# ld: undefined reference to 'eax'

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, ld

I have never encounted this error on my old linux machine(both are intel 32bit) so I am at a loss.

I am trying to assemble and link assembly code (which is very simplistic and should work) but `ld` is giving the error

```
rs.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `eax'
```

the line in question is the `pushl %eax` line. I only need to push a single byte of 0 to the stack so I decided to use the xor'd `eax` register. but `pushb` gives me an "*invalid suffix or operands for push*" error while assembling with `as` using the code `pushb %al` and if I try to use `pushl %eax` `as` assembles fine but the linker yells at me.

here is the code.

```
.section .data

.section .text

.global _start

_start:

xorl %eax, %eax

#sys_socketcall(int call, __user *args)
#sys_socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)

pushl %eax          #protocol: 0
pushl $1            #type: SOCK_STREAM
pushl $2            #domain: AF_INET
movL $1, %ebx       #sys_socket
movl $102, %eax    #sys_socketcall
int $0x80

movl $eax, %ebx  #move socket fd to check echo $?
movl $1, %eax    #exit
int $0x80
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: No way is `pushl %eax` at `_start + 0x11`. `movl $eax, %ebx`, on the other hand....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in your assembly: `$eax` should be `%eax` in

```
movl $eax, %ebx  #move socket fd to check echo $?
```

Comment: thank you a silly mistake on my end. will accept your answer in 6 minutes. it fixed my linker problem. one more question though. why is 'push %al' and 'pushb %al' returning the error: suffix or operands invalid for push.

Comment: @bobmoch You can't push 8-bit registers in `x86` assembly. You have to use `push %ax`/`pushw %ax`, `push %eax`/`pushd %eax` or `push %rax`/`pushq %rax` instead.

Comment: i see. thanks for the info. ive also read perilbrain's links and it makes more sense now. thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 3):

I could imagine it is the

```
movl $eax, %ebx  #move socket fd to check echo $?
```

line.

Instead, it should be

```
movl %eax, %ebx  #move socket fd to check echo $?
```

...

Answer (score 3):

```
movl $eax, %ebx
```

is problematic. It tries to load the **address of a symbol named `eax` into ebx,** which is not what you want. Change that typo into

```
movl %eax, %ebx
```

to tell it to do what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Besides syntatical errors,the problem is you cant push bytes on stack.
Look at

http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Assembler/comp.lang.asm.x86/2006-03/msg00253.html

http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc266.htm

I will suggest using pushw %ax if possible.